# lineinfile on all matches

Tags: ansible

Since `lineinfile` only check the first or last match, is there a way I can use it to edit my file as I wanted on all matches?

Example : I have a file like the one below and I want to add `ZZZ` after all `AAA` matches.

Source file:

```
AAA
BBB
AAA
CCC
DDD
```

Desired output :

```
AAA
ZZZ
BBB
AAA
ZZZ
CCC
DDD
```

I tried the module `replace`, but since it has to match a regex, I don't really know how I can write it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write your task:

```
  tasks:
    - name: replace
      replace:
        path: ./pathoffile
        regexp: '^(AAA)$'
        replace: '\1\nZZZ'
```

or if you dont want to use group regex

```
    regexp: '^AAA$'
    replace: 'AAA\nZZZ'
```

use    `regex: '^(AAA)$(?!\nZZZ)'`  if you want to change only `AAA` not followed by `\nZZZ`

Answer (score 2):

The solution below works, but it's not idempotent. The backreference `'\1\nZZZ'` will make no difference

```yaml
    - replace:
        path: test.txt
        regexp: '^AAA$'
        replace: 'AAA\nZZZ'
```

Running the play in check and diff mode `--check --diff` you can see the newline `\nZZZ` will be added repeatedly

```yaml
TASK [replace] ********************************************
--- before: test.txt
+++ after: test.txt
@@ -1,7 +1,9 @@
 AAA
+ZZZ
 ZZZ
 BBB
 AAA
 ZZZ
+ZZZ
 CCC
 DDD
```

Use Python regex **negative lookahead assertion** `(?!...)` to make the task idempotent. The *regexp* below will match only if `AAA\n` is not followed by `ZZZ`

```yaml
    - replace:
        path: test.txt
        regexp: 'AAA\n(?!ZZZ)'
        replace: 'AAA\nZZZ\n'
```

Comment: Exactly, This is what I came up with in the end. Thanks